# Ellipsized TextView in ListView item not working

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I've got an xml file for a ListView item. it looks like this, containing three textviews:
[image]

Now, the second TextView in the middle sometimes got text that is too long to fit between the other two TextViews. That's why I wanted to make it ellipsized.

My .xml file looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card_background" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/test"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="75dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_textview1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_textview3"
        android:text="@string/test"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_textview3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/test"
        android:textColor="#DEDEDE"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As You might see in the center TextView values, I've added

```
 android:singleLine="true"
 android:ellipsize="marquee"
 android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
 android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

But the result is just a long text, shorten with three points at the end. It just won't move?

Here's an image:
[image]

This center TextView does not scroll. 
Note that it's an item of a ListView. That's why I tried to made the center TextView focusable, what ended in not being able to press on the list item.

Any ideas?

Comment: Request focus on your marquee: `TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list_textview3);` then `textView3.setSelected(true);`

Comment: @zgc7009 worked very well, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've got the solution from user zgc7009 :

I just had to add:

```
TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list_textview3);
textView3.setSelected(true);
```

Worked nicely, thanks!